# How to bind data in gridview in asp.net without using properties

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have this code I want to bind data to grid view without using properties .

```
        public class UserTerritory
        {
           public string TerrId;
           public string TerrName;
           public string AccAccessLevel;

           public UserTerritory(string _TerrId, string _TerrName, string _AccAccessLevel)
           {
              this.TerrId = _TerrId;
              this.TerrName = _TerrName;
              this.AccAccessLevel= _AccAccessLevel;
           }
        }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<UserTerritory> ut = new List<UserTerritory>();
        ut.Add(new UserTerritory("1", "x", "a"));
        ut.Add(new UserTerritory("2", "y", "b"));
        ut.Add(new UserTerritory("3", "z", "c"));



        grdUserTerr.DataSource = ut;
        grdUserTerr.DataBind();
    }
```

When I execute the above code I get following Httpexception "  The data source for GridView with id 'grdUserTerr' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content."

Can Somebody tell me what wrong I am doing ?

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that databinding uses DataBinder.Eval (or just Eval ) behind the scenes and it
looks only for properties. They aren't exactly the same as public members (fields). Properties are closer to methods than fields are.

So why don't you just use properties like this?

```
public string AccAccessLevel { get; set; }    
public string TerrName  { get; set; }    
public string TerrId { get; set; }
```

Comment: thks for your reply it was nice to look in depth in eval

Comment: @vishal why you accept this as answer even in your question you make this "How to bind data in gridview in asp.net without using properties"

Answer (score -1):

there is problem some where in the property decalration section please change the properties as private memeber it will works for you.

```
 public class UserTerritory
        {
           private string TerrId;
           private string TerrName;
           private string AccAccessLevel;

           public UserTerritory(string _TerrId, string _TerrName, string _AccAccessLevel)
           {
              this.TerrId = _TerrId;
              this.TerrName = _TerrName;
              this.AccAccessLevel= _AccAccessLevel;
           }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . I change the property declaration but I am still getting the same exception

Comment: one idea is that you can change the private fields into properties , i am looking also in this approach , if i find any solution i will post as i find.

Comment: who make this votedown ? please read comment carefully before such vote down.and please also give the valid reason in comment for such vote down/